# Slide framelayout to left/right, fade and execute method

Tags: java, android, animation

I have the following framelayout:

```
        <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/example"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">                
        </FrameLayout>
```

What I'd like to do is be able to toggle it rightways / left in relation to its parent div, fade it and execute a method, left or right differently. I've never done animation in android and don't know if there is something premade (being native, +) that also executes a method at the end of animation + fade. Any idea on this one?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to know [**How to handle right to left swipe gestures**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4139288/android-how-to-handle-right-to-left-swipe-gestures) and add fade based on

`float diffY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();`

and

`float diffX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();`

variables (the length of your gestures' vectors) from code example shown there.